# Updating a txt file content

Tags: c, file

So I could finish (not totally correct, yet fine for me) a listage of contents from a file called **order.txt**

The file has the following

Let's say our current time is **14:59**

**order.txt**

> file1.txt;5;15:00
>
> file2.txt;6;15:01
>
> file3.txt;7;15:02
>
> file1.txt;2;15:03
>
> file1.txt;5;15:05
>
> file2.txt;2;15:06
>
> file1.txt;3;15:07

**So basically,** "fileName";"lists for X seconds";"starts listing at ##:##"

The file will open and then list all the content by the order given above, untill that, it's fine.

Yet, now I need to save each file when used, with the number of total listages it has, and the total time it was listed, and if it has listing time or not (basically, if it is in the order.txt file)

**For example, it's supposed to be like this:**

**used.txt**

> file1.txt;4;15;1 **(1 - Is in the order.txt, 0 - Its not, I can do this one after this is done, it will change when I remove it's time)**
>
> file2.txt;2;8;1
>
> file3.txt;1;7;1

**Basically,** "fileName";"totalTimeItAppears";"totalSecondsItShows";"IfItIsInOrder.txt"

And, if the user decides to show order.txt again and it still remains the same, of course, it needs to update again and will have new values (which in this case will be twice the above)

**used.txt**

> file1.txt;8;30;1
>
> file2.txt;4;16;1
>
> file3.txt;2;14;1

I've tried to do my code already but it only worked the first time, and probably only if there were twice the same value, in this case, file1.txt is shown 4 times so it probably won't work, so I deleted the code. I've tried to think different ways of doing it but can't come to an idea to correctly update it.

**This is my code that shows the order.txt:**

```
        orderFile = fopen("order.txt","r");

        if(orderFile != NULL)
        {
            fseek(orderFile, 0, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(orderFile);
            rewind(orderFile);

            if(size == 0)
            {
                printf("\n< No files to list >\n\n");
                fclose(orderFile);
            }
            else
            {
                while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]\n",fileName,&seconds,timeValue) == 3)
                {
                    contentFile = fopen(fileName,"r");

                    if(contentFile != NULL)
                    {
                        sscanf(timeValue,"%d:%d",&hour,&min);
                        fseek(contentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
                        size = ftell(contentFile);
                        rewind(contentFile);

                        if(size == 0)
                        {
                            printf("\n< Scanned File has nothing to list >\n\n");
                            fclose(contentFile);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            time_t now;
                            time(&now);

                            struct tm file_time_tm;
                            file_time_tm = *localtime(&now);
                            file_time_tm.tm_hour = hour;
                            file_time_tm.tm_min = min;
                            file_time_tm.tm_sec = 0;
                            file_time_tm.tm_isdst = -1;
                            time_t fileTime = mktime(&file_time_tm);

                            diff_time = difftime(fileTime, now);

                            if(diff_time > 0)
                            {
                                defaultFile = fopen("default.txt","r");
                                while(fscanf(defaultFile,"%[^\t]",defaultContent) == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("%s\n", defaultContent);
                                }
                                fclose(defaultFile);
                                sleep(diff_time);

                                while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("%s\n", textContent);
                                }
                                fclose(contentFile);
                                sleep(seconds);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(diff_time < 0)
                                {
                                    diff_time2 = diff_time + 86400;

                                    defaultFile = fopen("default.txt","r");
                                    while(fscanf(defaultFile,"%[^\t]",defaultContent) == 1)
                                    {
                                        printf("%s\n", defaultContent);
                                    }
                                    fclose(defaultFile);
                                    sleep(diff_time2);

                                    while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
                                    {
                                        printf("%s\n", textContent);
                                    }
                                    fclose(contentFile);
                                    sleep(seconds);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(diff_time == 0)
                                    {
                                        while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
                                        {
                                            printf("%s\n", textContent);
                                        }
                                        fclose(contentFile);
                                        sleep(seconds);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sscanf(timeValue,"%d:%d",&hour,&min);
                        printf("\n< File does not exist >\n\n");
                        fclose(contentFile);
                    }
                }

        fclose(orderFile);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n< File does not exists, please create it again >\n\n");
            fclose(orderFile);
        }

        printf("\n");
```

All I know is that after the **sleep(seconds)** I should add it to the **used.txt**, but I don't know how to add it only once, and if there's another update that line. I though about using the "r+" so it would write on top of that line, yet in my program I can rename files, so if a file1.txt would be renamed to file.txt, one character would still be there, and in the end would be ;11 (1 or 0 was supposed to be).

Any idea of how to add it while correctly updating everytime the file goes?

---

I've tried this so far:

```
tempFile = fopen("temp.txt","w");
utilizadosFicheiro = fopen("utilizados.txt","r");

while(fscanf(utilizadosFicheiro," %49[^;];%d;%d;%d",ficheiroNome,&nApresentacao,&tempoAcumulado,&escalonamento) == 4)
{
  fseek(tempFile, 0, SEEK_END);
  size = ftell(tempFile);
  rewind(tempFile);

  if(size == 0)
  {
    fprintf(tempFile,"%s;%d;%d;%d\r\n",ficheiroNome,nApresentacao,tempoAcumulado,escalonamento);
  }
  else
  {

    while(fscanf(tempFile," %49[^;];%d;%d;%d",ficheiroNome2,&nApresentacao2,&tempoAcumulado2,&escalonamento2) == 4)
    {
      if(strcmp(ficheiroNome,ficheiroNome2) == 0)
      {
         // Edit the line with tempFile "r+"
      }
      else
      {
         // Keep line with tempFile "r"
         fprintf(tempFile,"%s;%d;%d;%d\r\n",ficheiroNome,nApresentacao,tempoAcumulado,escalonamento);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> ficheiroNome = fileName
>
> nApresentacao = timesListedNumber
>
> tempoAcumulado = totalSecondsListed
>
> escalonamento = "time" (will either be 1 or 0)

Comment: From what scraps I was able to understand, easiest way is "load file into memory structures -> modify structures -> write entire file back".

Comment: Hm I'm not sure how to do that, by the way, I edited my post and made a code to the update part, do you mind to check it out and see if it's correct? And what should I do where there's comments (code)

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to answer with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct used_entry_s {
    char name[128];
    int num_occurances;
    int seconds_total;
    int in_order_flag;
};

struct order_entry_s {
    char name[128];
    int seconds;
    unsigned long long start;
};

/* first read from used.txt */
int read_entries(struct used_entry_s *entries) {
    FILE *f = fopen("used.txt", "r");
    struct used_entry_s entry;
    int ne = 0;

    if(!f) {
        return 0;
    }

    while(fscanf(f, "%[^;];%d;%d;%d\n", entry.name, &entry.num_occurances,
                &entry.seconds_total, &entry.in_order_flag) == 4) {
        memcpy(&entries[ne], &entry, sizeof(entry));
        ne++;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return ne;
}

/* save in-memory used entries to file, overwriting its contents */
void save_entries(const struct used_entry_s *entries, int num_entries) {
    int i;
    FILE *f = fopen("used.txt", "w");
    if(!f) {
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i != num_entries; ++i) {
        fprintf(f, "%s;%d;%d;%d\n", entries[i].name, entries[i].num_occurances,
                entries[i].seconds_total, entries[i].in_order_flag);
    }

    fclose(f);
}

/* update in-memory entries with given file */
int update_entries(const char *filename, struct used_entry_s *entries,
        int num_entries) {
    int ne = num_entries;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    char time_str[128];
    struct order_entry_s entry;

    if(!f) {
        return num_entries;
    }

    while(fscanf(f, "%[^;];%d;%[^\n]\n", entry.name, &entry.seconds, time_str) == 3) {
        /* maybe convert time_str to time_t here, I'm too lazy for that */

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i != ne; ++i) {
            if(strcmp(entries[i].name, entry.name) == 0) {
                /* got match, update it */
                entries[i].seconds_total += entry.seconds;
                entries[i].num_occurances++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(i == ne) {
            /* no match found - add new one */

            strcpy(entries[ne].name, entry.name);
            entries[ne].num_occurances = 1;
            entries[ne].seconds_total += entry.seconds;
            entries[ne].in_order_flag = 1;

            /* increase number of entries */
            ne++;
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return ne;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* maximum number of entries in used.txt */
#define MAX_USED_ENTRIES 128
    struct used_entry_s used_entries[MAX_USED_ENTRIES];
    int num_entries = read_entries(used_entries);

    num_entries = update_entries("order.txt", used_entries, num_entries);
    num_entries = update_entries("order.txt", used_entries, num_entries);

    save_entries(used_entries, num_entries);

    return 0;
}
```

It relies on MAX_USED_ENTRIES to be a constant and never checks for overflow. This could be improved if required, but it isn't question's topic.